# Consulta con sentencia WHERE en CodeIgniter no funciona

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

estoy tratando de hacer consultas simples a una base de datos MySQL desde CodeIgniter. Para eso tengo una vista llamada "Menú", aquí la voy a llenar con 3 categorías: Comidas(2), Bebidas(1) y Postres(3). En la base de datos tengo 2 tablas, `producto` y `categoria` la cual presento a continuación:

```
tabla producto

id, nombre, descripcion,precio,imagen,negocio_id,categoria_id

tabla categoria
id. nombre --Aquí va el nombre(Comidas, bebidas o postres)
```

En el modelo `MenuModel` tengo estas funciones:

```
    public function getAllComidas($id=2)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from(TABLE_PRODUCTO);
    $this->db->where('categoria_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();

}

public function getAllBebidas($id=1)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from(TABLE_PRODUCTO);
    $this->db->where('categoria_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();

}

public function getAllPostres($id=3)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from(TABLE_PRODUCTO);
    $this->db->where('categoria_id',$id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();

}
```

En el controlador tengo lo siguiente:

```
 public function index()
 {  


$data['menu'] = $this->MenuModel->getAllComidas();
    $this->load->view('estaticos/header');          
    $this->load->view('dinamicos/menu/menus', $data);
    $this->load->view('estaticos/menu_izquierdo');
    $this->load->view('estaticos/footer');  
    $this->load->view('estaticos/menu_derecho');
}



public function getBebidas()
 {

$data['menuBebidas'] = $this->MenuModel->getAllBebidas();

    $this->load->view('estaticos/header');          
    $this->load->view('dinamicos/menu/menus', $data);
    $this->load->view('estaticos/menu_izquierdo');
    $this->load->view('estaticos/footer');  
    $this->load->view('estaticos/menu_derecho');

}



public function getPostres()
{

    $data['menuPostres'] = $this->MenuModel->getAllPostres();
    $this->load->view('estaticos/header');          
    $this->load->view('dinamicos/menu/menus', $data);
    $this->load->view('estaticos/menu_izquierdo');
    $this->load->view('estaticos/footer');  
    $this->load->view('estaticos/menu_derecho');


}
```

En la vista utilizo esto para mostrar los datos llamando solo la función de comidas:

```
 <?php
                foreach ($menu as $menu) {
                  echo '

            <div class="box-body">
              <ul class="products-list product-list-in-box">
                <li class="item">
                  <div class="product-img">


                    <img  src="'.base_url('assets/dist/img/default-50x50.gif').'" alt="Product Image">
                  </div>

                  <div class="product-info">

                    <a href="javascript::;" class="product-title">'.$menu['nombre'].'<span class="label label-warning pull-right">Editar</span></a>

                    <span class="product-description">'
                     .$menu['descripcion'].'
                    </span>
                     <span class="label label-danger pull-right">eliminar</span></a>
                     <a onclick="if(confirma() == false) return false" href="'.base_url().'MenusController/borrar_item/'.$menu['id'].'">Eliminar</a>
                  </div>

                </li><!-- /.item -->




              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.box-body -->';
                       }
              ?>
```

Y si me funciona, me muestra las comidas:

[image: comidas]

Pero si vuelvo a utilizar el mismo fragmento de código y solo cambiando el nombre de la función por ejemplo a :

```
foreach ($menu as $menuBebidas)
```

Me muestra un elemento repetido y no todas las bebidas o postres dependiendo del ID:

[image: bebidas]

Les agradecería que me dijeran en que estoy mal. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que en el index esta llamando los datos solo de la función **getallComidas()**

```
public function index(){
  $data['menu'] = $this->MenuModel->getAllComidas();
  $this->load->view('estaticos/header');          
  $this->load->view('dinamicos/menu/menus', $data);
  $this->load->view('estaticos/menu_izquierdo');
  $this->load->view('estaticos/footer');  
  $this->load->view('estaticos/menu_derecho');
}
```

Para cada menu deberias llamar cada función si quieres usarlas por ejemplo asi:

```
public function index(){
  $data['menu'] = $this->MenuModel->getAllComidas();
  $data['menuBebidas'] = $this->MenuModel->getAllBebidas();
  $data['menuPostres'] = $this->MenuModel->getAllPostres();
  $this->load->view('estaticos/header');          
  $this->load->view('dinamicos/menu/menus', $data);
  $this->load->view('estaticos/menu_izquierdo');
  $this->load->view('estaticos/footer');  
  $this->load->view('estaticos/menu_derecho');
}
```

y luego en la vista tienes que llamarlos en un foreach para cada menú:

```
foreach ($menu as $menu){
  //presentar datos
}

foreach ($menuBebidas as $menu){
  //presentar datos
}

foreach ($menuPostres as $menu){
  //presentar datos
}
```

No te olvides que codeigniter envía cada elemento del arreglo **$data** como una nueva variable, es decir para recorrer cada menú tienes que usar esas variables en el `foreach`.

Comment: Ah ok eso de los foreach si no hay problema, eh ahí que surgió mi duda, porque al momento de llamarlos dependiendo si era bebida o comida me repetía datos. Gracias, deja lo reviso lo que dices y comento los resultados.

Comment: La verdad era muy sencillo, te debo una, gracias :D

Comment: ok, de nada, un gusto ayudar a la comunidad.